# How can I search for questions?

Tags: discussion

I'm brand new to the Blender Stack Exchange and relatively new to using Blender.

My first question is in regards to using the Stack Exchange itself. How can I search for questions so I don't have to post a new question if the answer I'm looking for is already answered?

I don't see a "Search" input anywhere.

Comment: Welcome! (1) See the top bar. (2) You have to download 2.8**2** from here: https://builder.blender.org/download/, Also see the release notes: https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Reference/Release_Notes/2.82/Physics

Comment: Thanks to both of you. After down;oading 2.8.2 I now seem to have Mantaflow installed! I couldn't post this on the meta section originally due to being a first time poster. Thanks agian!

Comment: Glad we could help. Consider to accept Duartes answer: https://blender.stackexchange.com/tour

Answer (score 1):

Builtin search is in the black header top bar above

While search can be done on site the builtin search engine, the results are not always the the best. It can't ignore typos, find synonyms nor similar terms.

Google is a good alternative. You can narrow down searching to this site using the filter `site:blender.stackexchange.com` like

[https://www.google.com/search?q=site:blender.stackexchange.com](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Ablender.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Thank you Duarte! I didn't see the top black header as it kind of blends into the Google search bar. I will use this in future. I did realize that this question should have been posted in the "meta" section, but I didn't think I could post it there as there was a message saying that I needed to have a reputation of "5", and I didn't think I had any reputation as I'd never been to this site before. I'm still fumbling my way around, but hopefully I'll get the hang of it.